# How do I render a table in a specific Layout() using the python rich Live() class

Tags: python, rich

Here is the code to create the layout

```
import time
from rich.live import Live
from rich.table import Table
from rich.layout import Layout
layout=Layout()
layout.split_row(
   Layout(name="left"),
   Layout(name="right"), )
print(layout)
```

I would like to display the below table in the right column but I can't figure out how

```
table = Table()
table.add_column("Row ID")
table.add_column("Description")
table.add_column("Level")

with Live(table, refresh_per_second=4):  # update 4 times a second to feel fluid
    for row in range(12):
        time.sleep(0.4)  # arbitrary delay
        # update the renderable internally
        table.add_row(f"{row}", f"description {row}", "[red]ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update your code to the following to make it work

```
import time
from rich.live import Live
from rich.table import Table
from rich.layout import Layout

layout = Layout()
layout.split_row(
    Layout(name="left"),
    Layout(name="right"), )
print(layout)

table = Table()
table.add_column("Row ID")
table.add_column("Description")
table.add_column("Level")

layout["right"].update(table)

with Live(layout, refresh_per_second=4):  # update 4 times a second to feel fluid
    for row in range(12):
        time.sleep(0.4)  # arbitrary delay
        # update the renderable internally
        table.add_row(f"{row}", f"description {row}", "[red]ERROR")
```